# Cannot insert minus sign into varchar column with check constraint (column <> '')

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, h2

I have an H2 table with a varchar column with a check constraint defined like this:

```
CONSTRAINT my_constraint CHECK (varchar_field <> '')
```

The following insert statement fails, but succeeds when I remove the constraint or insert any other value that is not just the minus sign ("-").

```
PreparedStatement ps= con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO my_table (id, varchar_field) VALUES (?, ?);");
ps.setInt(1, id);
ps.setString(2, "-"); 
ps.executeUpdate();
```

Update: further tests reveal behavior that I do not understand. Is the minus sign some kind of string literal operator in SQL/H2 database? If yes, how do I escape it?

[image]

Comment: This may be an issue with the Beta version of H2 that you are using. I just tried the same thing with the latest stable release (1.3.176) and `SELECT '-' = '' AS result;` returned `FALSE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Gord's comment I tested with H2 1.3.176, but I still had the same problem. When I created a new test database, I did not observe the problem.

-> For the new test db i did not specify a collation, but the application db is created with "COLLATION=ENGLISH STRENGTH PRIMARY".

I really didn't expect primary strength collation to cause `('-' = '')` to evaluate to true... I will have to revisit my own question from a few years ago: [H2 database collation strength: what to choose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13849244/h2-database-collation-strength-what-to-choose).

I am again very confused and unsure about what collation I should use.

Comment: To recap: **specifying a collation ENGLISH STRENGTH PRIMARY causes the comparison of the constraint to consider a minus a non-sign.** Like "sublist" and "sub-list" being _equal_.

Comment: Try `CHECK LENGTH(varchar_field) > 0`.

Answer (score 1):

As documented, H2 uses java.text.Collator, so you get the same result as with that class. Example:

```
java.text.Collator c = Collator.getInstance();
c.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY);
System.out.println(c.compare("-", "") == 0);
System.out.println(c.compare("-", "  ") == 0);
System.out.println(c.compare("-", "--") == 0);
```

Result:

```
true
true
true
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, Thomas. I just never thought that the primary strength collator would behave like that. For my new project I am now leaning towards using no collation at all, VARCHAR_IGNORECASE columns for some unique secondary keys, and rely on application code instead of SQL for all sorting requirements (still thinking about searching).

Comment: It's sometimes good if you have a method that converts your user data to a byte array or string that is easily sortable. And maybe you can convert this back to your user data.